# Issues in EditText

Tags: java, android

My issue is when first `EditText` length greater than 10 then second `EditText` will be enabled and second `EditText` length greater than 8 then after `Button` will be enabled what is the problem in my code? Please any one can solve this problem.

```
public void loginPage(View v) {
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pasword);
    username = editText.getText().toString();
    password = editText1.getText().toString();
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login1);
    editText1.setEnabled(false);
    btn.setEnabled(false);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() >= 10) {
                editText1.setEnabled(true);
                btn.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() >= 8) {
                btn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your English; sorry. Please, rephrase.

Comment: you have to add TextWatcher in order to know where it will reach 10 or 8

Comment: If you want to enable the 2nd EditText and button while user types, you gotta implement textWatcher.. If you want to enable them after user clicks on the button, tour current code is right

Comment: got it problem of yours ...... just cut the first 7 line of loginPage() method and paste it in OnCreate() method .

Comment: loginPage() only write the working of intent only .And all the methods just write in the OnCreate() method .

Answer (score 5):

**Use this for the equal or greater than 10 word**

paste this method in `OnCreate()` method

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() >= 10)
                editText1.setEnabled(true);
            else
                editText1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

**and for the button for 8 words**

paste this method in `OnCreate()` method

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
    
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() >= 8)
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
               else
                    btn.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
```

enjoy coding .........

Comment: i want code for enable@sushil kumar not for visible

Comment: first disable your editText2 and btn in the xml and then use it .

Comment: no @sushilkumar actually loginPage is my onClick().when i click on login button then after that second edittext and login field disabled.when we dont click its normally appeared like working components

Comment: see my code above @sushilkumar still it shows normal edittext it doesnt disabled still

Comment: bro paste your full activity code or full class code please ..... read my edit answer carefully .

Answer (score 2):

**You need to use `Text Watcher` with `Edit Text`.**

`Try this code.`

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText, editText1;
    Button btn;
    String username, password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        loginPage();
    }

    public void loginPage()

    {

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        username = editText.getText().toString();
        password = editText1.getText().toString();
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login1);
        editText1.setEnabled(false);
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() >= 10) {
                    editText1.setEnabled(true);
                    btn.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() >= 8) {
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

`Create new function to Change from Login page on Button Click.`

```
public void changeLoginPage(){
     Intent intentNew = new Intent(First.this,Destinatin.this);
     startActivity(intentNew);
}
```

and add this on `onCreate` method.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        changeLoginPage();
     }
});
```

Comment: loginpage(View v) is my onClick() method.its not workng

Comment: @AnilkumarJohn Remove `(View v)` from `loginpage(View v)` no need to add that directly call pn `onCreate` as i have done in above code `loginPage();` call only.

Comment: @AnilkumarJohn What you need to do on `Button Click` ?

Comment: its workng but i want this code with onclick method then what i do @jaydroider

Comment: @AnilkumarJohn Can you tell me simply what you need to do on `Button Click` ? Please explain

Comment: when we use onclick method the button action takes place that method parameters took with view refernce.for doing action h button onclick method we used

Comment: its workng but when i using loginPage() error shows like unfortunately login has stopped when i click on that button

Comment: @AnilkumarJohn Let me know if you face any problem in edited answer.

Comment: @jaydroider loginPage(View view) is click listener and he puts all code in that click listener . I think he is new comer .